# Permmission denied while opening file from Temp folder

Tags: java, permissions, ioexception

In my `Temp` folder, there is one file which is downloaded from browser. I am trying to open this file using `Desktop`API like this :

```
File f = new File("C:/DOCUME~1/NJAGAD~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/7870249-0/1234567.pptx");
      try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

But it gives error like :

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/DOCUME~1/NJAGAD~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/7870249-0/1234567. Error message: Access is denied.

    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is 99% certain to be a permissions problem, or the file is open exclusively in another program.  Is the Java program running as the owner of the temp folder?  Use Sysinternals' Process Explorer to figure out what other process has the file open.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got the error java.io.IOException: Failed to open "PDF" files. Error message: Access is denied. The following solution resolved the issue.

Solution:

Open the PDF reader
      Go to Edit --> Preferences
      General --> Select Default Handler --> Select Adobe product --> apply -->ok --> Restart the computer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access folders in windows partition you have to change permission. Otherwise you will get this exception.